# Chart can't be copied with Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, pie-chart

I am writing data to an excel file with openpyxl, I also added a pie chart with openpyxl.
I duplicate the whole sheet I am working on with this simple code:

```
source = wb.active
target = wb.copy_worksheet(source)
```

Every cell and all the data gets copied correctly to the duplicate sheet but the pie chart which is completely absent. Is there a reason related to the inner workings of openpyxl that makes it unable to copy charts to a new sheet?

Comment: pls refer [usage](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html). they have a warning "openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are opened and saved with the same name."

Comment: You are right. Some elements, including charts, won't be read hence also not copied to a duplicate sheet.

Comment: The scope of `copy_worksheet` is deliberately restricted to focus on worksheet data.

Answer (score 1):

As reported by @simpleApp and stated here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html, openpyxl is not yet capable to read all the elements from an excel sheet. This includes charts. So the only workaround I found is to programmatically write the charts to the duplicate sheet.